# Почему wait/notify/notifyAll методы в Java вызываются из синхронизированных блока или метода?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Почему `wait/notify/notifyAll` методы в `Java` вызываются из синхронизированных блока или метода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Секция synchronized указывает какие именно потоки будут выходить из wait при вызове notify. То есть:

```
class A {
    synchronized void a() {
        notify(); // #1
        wait();   // #2
    }
}

class B {
    synchronized void b() {
        notify(); // #3
        wait();   // #4
    }
}
```

При вызове notify из #3 проснется поток, который спал в wait из #4. Но никак не #2. Это же актуально и для разных объектов. А теперь если сделать во так

```
class C {
    static Object lock = new Integer();
}

class A {
    void a() {
        synchronized(C.lock) {
            notify(); // #1
            wait();   // #2
        }
    }
}

class B {
    void b() {
        synchronized(C.lock) {
            notify(); // #3
            wait();   // #4
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь при вызове notify из #3 может проснуться как поток спящий на #4, так и на #2.

Answer (score 2):

> An object’s intrinsic lock and its intrinsic condition queue are
>   related: in order to call any of the condition queue methods on object
>   X, you must hold the lock on X. This is because the mechanism for
>   waiting for state-based conditions is necessarily tightly bound to the
>   mechanism for preserving state consistency: you cannot wait for a
>   condition unless you can examine the state, and you cannot release
>   another thread from a condition wait unless you can modify the state.

© Brian Goetz "Java Concurrency in Practice"

Вне синхронизированного блока у вас нет гарантии очерёдности событий, происходящих в разных потоках. Более того, один поток может так никогда и не узнать о том, что другой поток изменил какое-либо состояние.

Comment: а вот я не понимаю зачем нужен wait/notify/notifyAll если есть метод join?